# MYSQL Slow Insertion and Update in Big Database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, query-optimization, my.cnf

I'm having trouble tuning mysql configuration to maximize the speed of insertion and update queries.

The problem occurs when we have to insert daily data approximately half a million record everyday and it would run for minutes before it completes.

While it performing the job I've checked and found out that it was using less than 5% for CPU and half of memory. My question is how can I increase the speed by maximize mysql to use all available resources.

Thank you.

**Performance**
**Insert/Update** is around 2,000-4,000 records per second on both MyISAM and InnoDB tables

**Table#1**
Engine: MyISAM
Columns : 21
Existed Rows : 5,400,000
Key : One Unique key on 7 columns and One Primary Key

**Table#2**
Engine: InnoDD
Columns : 14
Existed Rows : 1,500,000
Key : One Primary Key, One Unique Key on 6 columns, Two Indexes

**Insert Method**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

**Hardware Specifications**

```
    2 x Intel Xeon E5-2640v2 2.1GHz, 20M Cache, 7.2GT/s
    RAM 16GB
    2 x HDD 300GB 15K RPM,6Gbps SAS 2.5
```

---

**my.cnf Configuration**

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=1
max_connections = 600
max_user_connections=1000
key_buffer_size = 3584M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 256K
table_open_cache = 5000
thread_cache_size = 384
wait_timeout = 20
connect_timeout = 10
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
net_buffer_length = 16384
max_connect_errors = 10
concurrent_insert = 2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 786432
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_limit = 5M
query_cache_size = 1024M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65535
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 8
log-error
external-locking=FALSE
open_files_limit=50000
#expire-logs-days = 7

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2024M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

sort_buffer_size = 512K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 512M


[mysqld_safe]

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M

#### Per connection configuration ####
sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
thread_stack = 192K
```

**MysqlTuner Results**

```
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 5G (Tables: 306)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 269M (Tables: 441)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 34

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 12h 58m 9s (4M q [37.247 qps], 70K conn, TX: 21B, RX: 1B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 67% / 33%
[--] Total buffers: 7.0G global + 2.2M per thread (600 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 8.3G (53% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (72/4M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (15/600)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 3.5G/1.5G
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.6% (304M cached / 1M reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 97.0% (3M cached / 3M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 11
[!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 14% (1K temp sorts / 9K sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 28% (1K on disk / 4K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (15 created / 70K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 74% (1K open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (831/50K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (755K immediate / 755K locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.0G/269.9M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
    sort_buffer_size (> 512K)
    read_rnd_buffer_size (> 1M)
```

Comment: "2,000-4,000 records per second" - sounds pretty good to me

Comment: @MitchWheat So there is no way I could achieve better speed? I'm getting approximately the same performance on my localhost which is a laptop so I was expecting on the high performance server would have a better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> query_cache_size = 1024M
>   query_cache_type = 1

Those are *bad*.  Everytime you write something to a table, the Query cache needs to have all references to that table removed.  1G is *much* too big; 50M is what I recommend.  Also, unless you have demonstrated a need for the Query cache, I recommend turning it OFF.

On the other hand, "Query cache efficiency: 97.0% (3M cached / 3M selects)" says that you are using the QC, and it is effective.  So perhaps you should leave it on, but shrink the size.

As for loading -- Are you 'replacing' the table?  Or adding to a table.  If you are replacing, then load into a new table, then RENAME TABLE to put it into place.

> tmp_table_size = 1G
>   max_heap_table_size = 512M

These are dangerously high.  If multiple threads needed tmp tables at the same time, you could run out of RAM.  Put them back to the defaults.

"Temporary tables created on disk: 28%" cannot necessarily be improved by increasing those settings.  If there are TEXT or BLOB columns, tmp tables will go to disk.  If you like, show us SHOW CREATE TABLE and the naughty SELECTs.

"Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance" -- That tool always says that.  It is almost always bogus advice.

Are you loading only via LOAD DATA?  You also mentioned UPDATE; please elaborate.

"5% for CPU" -- How many 'cores' do you have?  Keep in mind that one MySQL connection will use only one CPU core.

"half of memory" -- That's bogus.  MyISAM is using some of the other half for caching data.  And nothing else can make use of the space.

Here's a potential optimization (for LOAD DATA):  Sort the data by the PRIMARY KEY before doing LOAD DATA.  Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE; there could be further tips in this area.

Do you delete 'old' data?  Is that time-based?  If so, let's talk about PARTITIONing.